# How to calculate the difference of numbers in series using Google sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an inventory sheet, where I need to calculate the difference between the actual value and the series of expected values. Here is a snapshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

So for `Item1`:

**Current: 50**

**Expected: 45,45,45**

Now I want to devise a formula that will calculate a difference until the last column in this specific row, something like this:

```
difference = 50-(45,45,45) //50-45+50-45+50-45 and so on (Q,R..)
difference = 15 //final result
```

Is there any way that we can achieve this by putting formula in a cell, any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In google-sheet you can use-

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(M2-N2:P2))
```

In excel use below formula

```
=SUM(M2-N2:P2)
```

In case of non 365 version of excel you need to enter it as array means confirm by `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just a small question, if we want to specify a whole row instead of 3 cells(N2,O2,P2), like instead of `=ArrayFormula(SUM(M2-N2:P2))`, can we use `=ArrayFormula(SUM(M2-N2:2))` ?

Comment: @Sohaib435 You can but in that case you may get unwanted result as every blank cell will be treated as zero and then every 0 will be minus from 50 like `50-45, 50-45, 50-45, 50-0, 50-0 .....` and so on.

Comment: Can we ignore blank cells so that it does not calculate 50-0,50-0 and so on

Comment: @Sohaib435 Can try this one `=ArrayFormula(SUM(M2-FILTER(N2:2,N2:2>0)))`. If it hels then accept the answer (tick mark it) to treat the thread as solved.